# Django ADFS auth mock for unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I use `django_auth_adfs` in my app. I need to mock it to perform view tests. The thing is that I've no idea which object should I mock.

This is my one of my test used before installation of `django_auth_adfs` and fixture draft.

```
class TestAPIVew:
    API_URL = reverse("list")

    @pytest.fixture
    def adfs(self):
        with patch('object_to_mock') as mock_auth:
            yield mock_auth

    def test_view_returns_correct_json(self, client, adfs):
        response = client.get(self.API_URL)
        data = response.json()
        assert response.status_code == HTTPStatus.OK
        assert data == {"key": "value"}
```

**QUESTION**

What should I do to omit `authentication` etc to make the test work as the user is logged in"